Как можно реализовать выбор пользователя на сайте (React)?
Логика такая: на странице choose person пользователь может выбрать 2 юзеров. При нажатии на серую область, его перекидывает на страницу с ранее добавленными юзерами. При нажатии на любого из них, данные об этом юзере добавляются в localStorage и пользователя перекидывает на страницу с выбором юзеров, где вместо серой области должно быть данные о юзере (точно такая же карточка на странице с юзерами). Мне нужно на странице выбора произвести проверку, если в localStorage данные имеются, вместо серой области появляется данные. Если в localStorage данные отсутствуют, то ничего не меняется. Пробовал сделать при помощи хуков, не получилось.
введите сюда описание изображения
const [firstPersonName, setPersonName] = useState('')
const [firstPersonDate, setPersonDate] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
  function checkPersonData() {
    const firstPersonName = window.localStorage.getItem('firstPersonName')
    const firstPersonDate = window.localStorage.getItem('firstPersonDate')

    console.log(firstPersonName)
    console.log(firstPersonDate)
    if (firstPersonName !== null && firstPersonName.length)
      setPersonName(firstPersonName)
    if (firstPersonDate !== null && firstPersonDate.length)
      setPersonDate(firstPersonDate)
  }

  checkPersonData()

  window.addEventListener('storage', checkPersonData)

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('storage', checkPersonData)
  }
}, [])


Зачем вам листнер изменения состояния localstorage? Он сработает, если изменения произойдут из другой вкладки. Добавьте компонент, как вы сохраняете значения в локалсторадж

Вам либо изменения пробрасывать пропсами, или через хранилище useContext или redux. Еще можно попробовать хук создать и там кастомный евент генерить
